# How can I force the value of a MySQL query to use a particular collation?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, uuid

I want to use `UUID()` to generate primary keys.

After some investigation, I thought this should work:

```
INSERT INTO aTable (`id`) VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')));
```

Where `id` is of the type `BINARY(16)`.

Unfortunately, `UUID()` returns a value which uses the `utf8_general_ci` collation. The rest of my database uses `utf8_unicode_ci`, which means I get the following error:

```
#1270 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'
```

How can I persuade `UUID()` to play nicely and use `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO aTable (`id`) VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID() COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,'-','')));
```