# MySQL concatenation and Illegal mix of collations error

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I keep getting an error using MySQL 5.5.27 when trying to concatenate some values.  I've searched and seen a bunch of charset answers (which admittedly is a TAD over my head), but I've converted all my tables to *Charset* `utf8-unicode-ci` and still get the error.

Surely there is a way to concatenate these values, but I just don't know how. I'm an Oracle guy that is relatively new to MySQL.

Here is the SQL line:

```
concat(pl.last_name,'-',format(money,0))
```

I get:

```
#1270 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'concat'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668989/how-can-i-force-the-value-of-a-mysql-query-to-use-a-particular-collation

Comment: This one might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753608/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-concat

Comment: Is your money column an integer? If not you can not use format, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format .

Comment: My money column is an integer.  Thanks for suggesting the links, but I had already tried each of those.  Incidentally, I don't have this problem locally.  I'm just having this on the host, where I'm encountering this in phpmyadmin.  When I run the same SQL locally (using TOAD for MySQL) it runs fine (just the straight concat; not needing the collate, etc, etc).

Comment: Anyway - on the host, I've also changed the charset on all my tables, and on the database itself... and still get errors.  When I run the sql using "Collate", I get:  #1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'.

Comment: Can you post your table structure with some sample data? I might help answer your question. Because I have tried to recreate you error an I have been unsuccessful. I use you query it works. You can post in http://www.sqlfiddle.com if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If money is indeed a number inside a VARCHAR you could use cast.

Try this:

```
concat_ws(pl.last_name,'-',cast(money AS unsigned)); // This is with decimals.
concat(`pl.last_name,'-',substring_index(money,',',1)) // Without decimals. If you use . i.e. the American currency notation you can substitute , with an .
```

**Edit**

Your should first try:  `concat(pl.last_name,'-',format(money,0))`;

This a very basic php code you could use.

```
<?php

function selecting_data(){

    $host = "host";
    $user = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";
    $charset = "utf8";

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    mysqli_set_charset($charset, $link);
    IF (!$link) {
        echo('Unable to connect to the database!');
    } ELSE {


        $query = "SELECT lastname, format(money,0) FROM mytable"; //Select query
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            echo $rows['lastname']."<br>".$rows['money'] ; 
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);


}
?>

<html>
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<?PHP echo selecting_data(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I believe my code is blowing on the pl.last_name - If I'm not mistaken, that's the one that keeps coming up "latin"...  and for full disclosure, and to betray my lack of PHP skills, initially I had the line returning "concat(pl.last_name,'<br>',format(money,0))" as the "cell" for a cross-tab query - forcing the two values onto two lines in my cell... but's that's digressing...  thanks for the help!

Comment: i.e. I think I want my pl.last_name to come up "unicode" to work with the <br> and "$" in the integer.

Comment: Oke, but you cannot mix php / html and mysql inside the query like that. You can do this with the output, but not with the query you sent to the mysql server.

Comment: Right, but it's actually just putting an html tag in the text, not mixing PHP/MySQL.  When it renders in the PHP variable, it puts a break between the two data elements, e.g. pl.last_name,'<br>',format(money,0)) = Line 1: Smith, Line 2: $50,000.  As I said - it works like a song locally... just not on the hosting server.  Makes me wonder if there's a difference in an ini setting

Comment: I don't know how to use the command line on the host - don't know if I can (just changed my host b/c the old one didn't support mysql stored procs).  Runs fine locally.

Comment: It probably works because you output the query directly in you html part of you php code.

Comment: Do you need concat? You might use the results from your query and fletch them through an array in PHP.

Comment: yeah - you're right about the array...  I could probably do this in a more efficient way.  I'm a newb though, and trying to keep my frontend code simple, and handling it in the crosstab query on the database...  anyway... maybe I should look at doing it with an array.  Basically, this is for a "golf pool" week-by-week results page.  The columns are the team_names, and the row headers are the event_names.  In the cell, I want the player_pick_name, and the amount of money earned for that event - the player name on top, the money beneath.

Comment: @user2059532 how is this possible? Did you change something?

Comment: Oops - didn't see your updated code above.  Thanks a bunch.  No, it always worked locally, just not on the host's server.  I need to step away for now - thanks a ton for your help.  I really appreciate it.  I'll look your code suggestion over and see if I can implement.

Comment: Anyway if my efforts where helpful you can accept my answer otherwise add your answer below and accept it for future reference.

Comment: Or is your problem still not solved? Reading back I have the impression that I have may misinterpreted your comment.